# How to make an nested Query or just look up if an foreign key exists in Aqueduct dart

Tags: dart, aqueduct

I was trying this for 5 hours and i could'n find an solution for this.
I want an nested query, for an many to many relationship. 
If I go with my User, Books, userBooksLikes example again. 
(For better understanding: I want to track in the userBookLikes Table which user likes what books. It has two forgeign keys, the IDs from Books and Users. ) I want to query books, on which an Like does not exist. So I need an SQL Query like this:

```
SELECT * FROM Book WHERE id NOT IN (SELECT bookID from userBooksLikes WHERE userID = givenUserID)
```

Or something similar to it. 
The only possibility to do that, that I found in the Documentation was

```
final q = Query<Parent>(context)
  ..where((c) => c.children.haveAtLeastOneWhere.age).greaterThan(1);
  ..join(set: (p) => p.children);

final parentsWithOlderChildren = await q.fetch();
```

But this seems not to work.
I made it now by deleting the data after the fetch, but i don't this this scales.

```
final bookQuery = Query<Book>(context);
   userID = 1;
   bookQuery
     .join(set: (e) => e.usrBookLikes).returningProperties((ubl) => [ubl.user.id]);

   final books = await BookQuery.fetch();
   books.forEach((e) => e.usrBookLikes.removeWhere((e) => e.user.id != userId));
   books.removeWhere((e) => e.usrBookLikes.isNotEmpty);
   books.forEach((e) => e.removePropertiesFromBackingMap(["usrBookLikes"]));
   return Response.ok(books);
```

Is there a way to do it with an database query?